# Java- JTable key bindings

Tags: java, swing, jtable, key-bindings

I wanted to change the default action of <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key on the JTable so that it has the same function as the <kbd>F2</kbd> key. So I used the key bindings and it works fine. Only one problem : if <kbd>F2</kbd> key is a second time on the same cell editing is stopped, but the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key don't do the same thing, it always start editing when pressed. Here's my code :

```
InputMap im = table.getInputMap(JTable.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT);
KeyStroke enter = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0);
KeyStroke f2 = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F2, 0);
im.put(enter, im.get(f2));
```

Thanks

Comment: While you are editing the cell, the focus is on the CellEditor being used. Any KeyEvent will be listened by the editor but not by the `JTable` itself. Damn! Should i made it an answer! :(

Comment: You still can and should!

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, i think i have already made a similar answer somewhere else. Searching for it and will add the link in the comment. That question wasn't exactly like this but a little more broad in sense.

Comment: If you have control over the editor, you can call stopEditing when the editors ActionPerfomred or equivalent event is performed